# How to declare a piped list in a Enum inside another Enum?

Tags: list, enums, arguments, pipe, elixir

I'm trying to use a piped list in a Enum inside another Enum. To try to make myself a little bit more clear, bellow is my code:

```
  def word_count(str) do
    String.downcase(str)
    |> String.split
    |> Enum.map(fn x -> Enum.count(LIST HERE, x) end)
  end
```

So what I want to do is to use the piped list as a parameter in the Enum.count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on the modern enough [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) (as you should be,) [`then/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#then/2) is your friend.

```elixir
"Foo bar foo"
|> String.downcase()
|> String.split()
|> then(&Enum.map(&1, fn x -> Enum.count(&1, fn y -> y == x end) end))
#⇒ [2, 1, 2]
```

The most readable solution would still be

```elixir
words =
  "Foo bar foo"
  |> String.downcase()
  |> String.split()

Enum.map(words, &Enum.count(words, fn x -> x == &1 end))
```

One should not try to keep a single pipe despite readability.

Answer (score 2):

The Enum functions take an enumerable as their first argument, so you can simply pipe a list into them.

If you want to count how many times each word appears, you can use [`Enum.frequencies/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies/1):

```elixir
def word_count(str) do
  str
  |> String.downcase()
  |> String.split()
  |> Enum.frequencies()
end
```

Example:

```elixir
iex> Example.word_count("foo bar baz")                            
%{"bar" => 1, "baz" => 1, "foo" => 1}
```

---

In this case `Enum.frequencies/1` was helpful, but often you can use [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) to write your own logic. Here is `Enum.frequencies/1` replaced with `Enum.reduce/3` that does the same thing:

```elixir
def word_count(str) do
  str
  |> String.downcase()
  |> String.split()
  |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn word, acc ->
    Map.update(acc, word, 1, fn count -> count + 1 end)
  end)
end
```

---

In response to the comments, using [`Kernel.then/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#then/2), with the disclaimer that there is probably a better way to do this depending on what is desired (like `reduce` above, or using comprehensions):

```elixir
1..10
|> then(fn one_to_ten ->
  Enum.map(one_to_ten, fn x ->
    Enum.map(one_to_ten, fn y ->
      {x, y}
    end)
  end)
end)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Adam. The code I posted is incomplete. What I want to do is pass a string as parameter, split it and then count how many times each words appears on the list. But I got stuck in how to use the piped list in a Enum inside another Enum

Comment: Ah, you can use [`Enum.frequencies/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies/1) for that. Updated the answer (I will also answer the enum in an enum part, just a minute...)

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. All your tips were very helpful. Regarding using the piped list in a Enum inside another Enum, do you know if that is possible?

Comment: Still not quite sure what you mean. Yes, it's possible but often I think `reduce` or something else will be better. Try `[[1,2],[3,4]] |> Enum.each(fn x -> Enum.each(x, &IO.puts/1) end)`.

Comment: In line 4 of the code I posted, there is a Enum.map which is receiving a list as the first parameter. In the function of this Enum.map I want to use another Enum which receive two parameters, and the first parameter I want to use the same list which the Enum.map received

Comment: I think you might be looking for [`Kernel.then/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#then/2).

Comment: @SamuelPereira I added another example to show it's possible, but I wouldn't write that code myself.